# GitHub app: Pre Commit Hook Entered [0;31m[Ruby Style][Fatal]: Add rubocop to your Gemfile[0m (1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, github, github-for-mac

I am using the `Github Mac App`. My employer recently required us to use a `pre commit hook` and now I can no longer commit from the app only the `terminal`

When committing from the app I get the error:

```
Pre Commit Hook Entered [0;31m[Ruby Style][Fatal]: Add rubocop to your Gemfile[0m(1)
```

Is there any sort of setup I need / can do to allow me to continue to use the app?

Comment: Did you *add rubocop to your Gemfile*?

Comment: @spickermann Yes. As I stated the committing through the terminal works fine.

Comment: I have the same problem. It came from the pre-commit hook script, if you are using a RVM or similar, bash loads ruby from the global enviroment instead of use of the project. I din't solve yet, but i think can be helpfull put absolute paths to your ruby version.